# Background color of bokeh layout

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm playing around with the Bokeh [sliders demo](https://demo.bokehplots.com/apps/sliders) (source code [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py)), and I'm trying to change the background color of the entire page. Though changing the color of the figure is easy using `background_fill_color` and `border_fill_color`, the rest of the layout still appears on top of a white background. Is there an attribute I can add to the theme that will allow me to set the color via `curdoc().theme`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's not currently any Python property that would control the HTML background color. HTML and CSS is vast territory, so instead of trying to make a corresponding Python property for every possible style option, Bokeh provides a general mechanism for supplying your own HMTL templates so that any standard familiar CSS can be applied.

This is most easily accomplished by adding a `templates/index.html` file to a [Directory-style Bokeh App](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#directory-format). The template should be  [Jinja2 template](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). There are two substitutions required to be defined in the `<head>`:

- `{{ bokeh_css }}`
- `{{ bokeh_js }}`

as well as two required in `<body>`:

- `{{ plot_div }}`
- `{{ plot_script }}`

The app will appear wherever the `plot_script` appears in the template. Apart from this, you can apply whatever HTML and CSS you need. You can see a concrete example here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/crossfilter

A boiled down template that changes the page background might look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            body { background: #2F2F2F; }
        </style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        {{ bokeh_css }}
        {{ bokeh_js }}
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
        {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @bigreddot I have the code as it is, from github link which you shared(Crossfilter example) but I still have the background as white. I had changed the hex number to #000000. Any idea why its still white?

Answer (score 3):

Changing the .bk-root style worked for me:

```
from bokeh.resources import Resources
from bokeh.io.state import curstate
from bokeh.io import curdoc, output_file, save
from bokeh.util.browser import view
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.plotting import figure 

class MyResources(Resources):
    @property
    def css_raw(self):
        return super().css_raw + [
            """.bk-root {
                    background-color: #000000;
                    border-color: #000000;
                    }
            """
        ]

f = figure(height=200, width=200)
f.line([1,2,3], [1,2,3])

tabs = Tabs( tabs=[ Panel( child=f, title="TabTitle" ) ], height=500 )

output_file("BlackBG.html")
curstate().file['resources'] = MyResources(mode='cdn')
save(tabs)
view("./BlackBG.html")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `row` or `column` for displaying several figures in the document, a workaround is setting the `background` attribute like this:

`curdoc().add_root(row(fig1, fig2, background="beige"))`

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the cleanest way to do it, but a workaround would be to modify file.html inside bokeh template folder

[FILE PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5vrj.png)

[CODE SNIPPET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNYOR.png)

Answer (score -1):

From [Bokeh documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#background):

> The background fill style is controlled by the background_fill_color
>   and background_fill_alpha properties of the Plot object:
>
> ```
> from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
>
> output_file("background.html")
>
> p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
> p.background_fill_color = "beige"
> p.background_fill_alpha = 0.5
>
> p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 8, 2, 7], size=10)
>
> show(p)
> ```

[image: plot with non-white background]

Comment: this does not change the background color of the entire figure though, e.g. the ticks are still on white background