# Holoviews change full background color

Tags: python, plot, holoviews

Very simple task but I haven't found a solution; I've made a Point plot with holoviews and I want to save the plot with a fully black background, the `bgcolor` only changes the inner area color, not the outside, which remains white. This is the plot:

[image]

How to change the color of this area?

Comment: That's a pretty plot! It's hard to answer the question without more details, such as what backend you are using, how you are saving it, etc.  A simple reproducible example would help make it concrete.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the bokeh backend since I'm using some interactive features, I obtain this image when I save it using the default save tool.

Comment: Ah, you're using the save icon in the toolbar?  Also try the hv.save() function, which may behave differently. In this case you probably need to set the page background color, which depends on whether you're using Jupyter (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429585/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-single-cell-in-a-jupyter-notebook-jupy) or Bokeh Server (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607084/background-color-of-bokeh-layout).